# JTabbedPane.getTabComponentAt(int) returning null

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have the following code :

```
JTabbedPane container;
...
AWindow page = WinUtils.buildWindow();
boolean existing = checkIfExists(page); // in this code, this will always be false
if(!existing)
{
    String tabName = page.getLoadedFileLocation().getName();
    container.addTab(page.getLoadedFileLocation().getName(), page);
}
Component comp = container.getTabComponentAt(0);
int sel = container.getSelectedIndex();
container.setSelectedComponent(page);
```

the thing is :

```
container.getTabComponentAt(0)
```

returns `null`. The other weird thing is :

```
container.getSelectedIndex()
```

returns `0`. The logical thing that I think should happen, is to have a reference to the created window. Why am I receiving `null`? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`getTabComponentAt()` returns the custom component you might add as the tab title. You might be looking for the `getComponentAt()` method to return the contents of a tab. The `getSelectedIndex()` just returns that the first tab is currently selected (it would return -1 for no tabs selected)

Answer (score 9):

You're confusing the two sets of methods in `JTabbedPane`: the tab component methods and the component methods.

[`getTabComponentAt(0)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getTabComponentAt(int)) is returning `null` because you haven't set the *tab component*. You've set the *component* that is displayed at index 0, but the *tab component* is the component that renders the tab--not the component that displays in the pane.

(Notice the example in the [Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html):

> ```
> // In this case the look and feel renders the title for the tab.
> tabbedPane.addTab("Tab", myComponent);
> // In this case the custom component is responsible for rendering the
> // title of the tab.
> tabbedPane.addTab(null, myComponent);
> tabbedPane.setTabComponentAt(0, new JLabel("Tab"));
> ```
>
> The latter is typically used when you want a more complex user interaction that requires custom components on the tab. For example, you could provide a custom component that animates or one that has widgets for closing the tab.

Normally, you won't need to mess with tab components.)

Anyway, try [`getComponentAt(0)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getComponentAt(int)) instead.